# Angular with Cypress test: how can I simulate click on a lazy loaded menu item?

Tags: angular, navigation, cypress

I tried to implement a minor cypress test, I just wanted to navigate to a lazy loaded page, but it not works for me.
The path: `'angular-page/angular-page-content1'`

What I tried:

```
describe('1st. test', () => {
  it('Visits the page', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.contains(`Welcome to`)
  })
  it('Navigate to the Angular page 1', () => {
    cy.get('a[href="/#/angular-page/angular-page-content1"]').click();
    cy.get('#title').should('have.text', 'Basic Template-Driven form and validation')
  })  
})
```

The source code found [here](https://lkovari.github.io/KLHome/#/angular-page/angular-page-content1).

What and where I missed?

Comment: Merge your tests together and try again. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation

Answer (score 2):

Luckily you do not have to simulate anything, Cypress does it for you with automatic retry of the selector until the page has been loaded.

But you do need to use the correct selector:

```js
cy.get('[class="sub-topic"]')
  .should('have.text', 'Basic Template-Driven form and validation')
```